# Getting cURL timeout error using Goutte, even with config settings

Tags: php, curl, goutte

Here's the code:

```
$this->baseUrl = "https://sfbay.craigslist.org/sfc/apa/";
$this->client = new Goutte\Client();
$curlOptions = array(
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 600,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 600
);
$this->client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config', ['curl' => $curlOptions]);
$crawler = $this->client->request("GET", $this->baseUrl);
```

And the error (repeated twice):

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException' with message '[curl] (#28) See http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html for an explanation of cURL errors [url] https://sfbay.craigslist.org/sfc/apa/' in /Users/...../vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Adapter/Curl/MultiAdapter.php:216`

The thing is: the code worked an hour ago, no issue! I added the cURL options after finding out error #28 is timeout.

Am I missing a cURL option? Or maybe I'm setting the values wrong? And why the change? I'm not on a significantly slower network (AFAIK).

Answer (score 2):

"GuzzleHttp" code has been updated. Hence you need to set the curl as follow

```
$client = new \Goutte\Client();

$guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(array(
    'curl' => array(
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
    ),
));
$client->setClient($guzzleClient);
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $my_url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out the issue with my code.

It was precedence. I placed this:

```
$client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/'.CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
$client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/'.CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 0);
$client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/'.CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
$client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/'.CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

before:

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $my_url);
```

And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue. Are you using goutte.phar downloaded from git?

If so, that is the problem.

Use the actual source files via autoloading composer and it should work.

Comment: No, I used the Composer version. But frankly, I moved on to better solutions... :)

Comment: Ah! Could you share what other solution works well for you?
I'm starting out with goutte, while I think it is workable, documentation is extensive so I'm taking longer than I think I need to...